# positioning and floating in css and compatibility code for cross browser designing

Tags: css, cross-browser, positioning

Can anyone of you give me a link to understand the positioning and floating in css so that my site could work in Firefox and chrome smoothly.
That will be very helpful for me.
And whats this compatibility code for cross browser css? please give some idea of the compatibility code also or link if you could.

Comment: Your question is very general and vague. Stack Overflow is designed for specific questions, preferably about an actual problem that you've encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris Coyier is always a good resource about CSS.

Some very good articles:

- [All about floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)
- [Quick Overview of CSS Position Values](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/110-quick-overview-of-css-position-values/) (screencast)
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Last one is about flexbox, which we all will use these coming days.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following links for float and position.

**Float**

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp
http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

**Position**

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Comment: w3schools isn't a good resource. See [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn the basic principles of positioning. Usually using a grid system is very effective in keeping standards and you will need to learn how floats act dependent on positioning. [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) is a very good resource and an excellent place to start.

There are also many web based solutions to test your code such as http://crossbrowsertesting.com/ (google) however, testing native on a VM or something similar will give you  more accurate results.